# Playwright Operation Chromium78 Version Application

Tags: python

For software built on Electron with Chromium version 78.0.3904.130, which version of Playwright can be used for automation? (I have tried using a newer version but was unable to perform any actions.)
The minimum version supported by Python, 1.9.0, cannot even start applications

Comment: The issue of not being able to operate should be caused by my specified port when starting the application, playwright being unable to connect to that port due to blockage

Playwright. chromium. launch (executable_path=path, args=["-- remote debugging port=9527"]) 
The current issue is that when using playwright to operate software with built-in Chromium, methods for operating Chrome such as new_context() and new_page() cannot be used.